# Cron job hang - how to debug?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I have some cronjob that sometimes gets stuck in running status.

That makes me think that for some reason they produce an error but I cannot find any related log. ( the column messages in `cron_schedule` is empty )

How can I be sure cron execution produces logs in case of errors?
How can I proceed to debug this issue, any advice?

**UPDATE**
It looks like my question is not clear, so I'm adding some more content ( I am not sure it gonna help because most of the people seem to read the title and guess the question ... )

- I know how cron works
- I know how to check if a cronjobs run or not
- My cronjobs correctly run

**The problem is some of the cronjobs do not end.**

To be more clear: `Mage_Cron_Model_Observer::_processJob()`

```
  $schedule
        ->setExecutedAt(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time()))
        ->save();

    call_user_func_array($callback, $arguments);

    $schedule
        ->setStatus(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::STATUS_SUCCESS)
        ->setFinishedAt(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time()));
```

The *status* is never reached for some cron, that is the problem.

**Please avoid give the random answer or just the first result google provide ( I know how to use google, I did my research ... )**

If the answer is not clear, just let me know.
If you wanna help you are more than welcome if you just won't waste my and your time you are not. ( this site is meant for quality answers, it is not a forum where everybody says his opinion ... posting not related answers will not help other people with the same issue ... but will just create confusion )

Comment: You can see the status in the column message of table cron_schedule in the database.

Comment: Try this magento extension https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler. It allows to manage cron jobs.

Comment: Is this an indexing job? If so, is it possible it being restarted when already running, resulting in a never ending reindex? In my experience, it's either a job that calls exit() preventing other jobs to run (yes, I've seen this in extensions) or jobs that overlap and use temporary tables, overwriting work already in progress.

Comment: @Abbas came on, really ?

Comment: @NicholasMiller I know that extension, is it is not helpful here ... thx

Comment: @Melvyn what you say makes sense but, not it is not an indexing ... anyway here I don't want to focus on a particular job (other users would not be interested ) but find a general approach to deal with this kind of problems

Comment: @Fra sorry at that time I understand you want to see the result of the cron. So that's why I recommend you to see the table.

Answer (score 0):

All of the fields should speak for themselves.

Copy and save the following PHP script.

```
<?php

    // Parse magento's local.xml to get db info, if local.xml is found

    if (file_exists('app/etc/local.xml')) {

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('app/etc/local.xml');

    $tblprefix = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;
    $dbhost = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
    $dbuser = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
    $dbpass = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
    $dbname = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;

    }

    else {
        exit('Failed to open app/etc/local.xml');
    }

    // DB Interaction
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to <a class="HelpLink" onclick="showHelpTip(event, hint_id_7); return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">mysql</a>');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $tblprefix . "cron_schedule") or die (mysql_error());


    // CSS for NexStyle
    echo '
    <html>
    <head>
    <title=Magento Cron <span style='background-color:#CCFF00;'>Status</span>>
    <style type="text/css">
    html {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    body {
        background-color:#00AEEF;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        line-height:1.0em;
        font-size: 125%;
    }
    b {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    table{
        border-spacing: 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 300px;
    }
    th {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 125%;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        background: #00AEEF;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 4px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background: #666;
    }
    </style>
    </head>';

    // DB info for user to see
    echo '
    <body>
    <a href="http://nexcess.net">
    <img src="https://smhttp-nex.nexcesscdn.net/803313/static/images/logoMainR2.gif" width="217" height="38" alt="Nexcess Beyond Hosting"></a>



    <b>Table Prefix:</b> ' . $tblprefix . ''
    . '<b>DB Host:</b> ' . $dbhost . ''
    . '<b>DB User:</b> ' . $dbuser . ''
    . '<b>DB Name</b>: ' . $dbname . '</p>';

    // Set up <span style="background-color:#CCFF00;">the</span> table
    echo "
            <table border='1'>
            <thread>
            <tr>
            <th>schedule_id</th>
               <th>job_code</th>
               <th><span style="background-color:#CCFF00;">status</span></th>
               <th>messages</th>
               <th>created_at</th>
               <th>scheduled_at</th>
               <th>executed_at</th>
               <th>finished_at</th>
               </tr>
               </thread>
               <tbody>";

    // Display <span style="background-color:#CCFF00;">the</span> data from <span style="background-color:#CCFF00;">the</span> query
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['schedule_id'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['job_code'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['<span style="background-color:#CCFF00;">status</span>'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['messages'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['created_at'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['scheduled_at'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['executed_at'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row['finished_at'] . "</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
    }

    // Close table and last few tags
    echo "</tbody></table></body></html>";

    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: I can open phpmyadmin if i need to check the cron, this is not the point.

Comment: Also when you provide an answer you should give a little of information, if the question is not clear you can always point it out

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my approach because it looks there is nothing better right now:

1. Disable the system cron for magento
2. now you can call the cron manually:

   `php cron.php -mdefault`

Calling the cron from cli should give more info in case of errors not captured by magento.

if you want to test a precise cronjob you may want to temporary alter `Mage_Cron_Model_Observer::_generateJobs`in order to force this job to always be schedule.

Here an example to force `catalog_product_alert`

```
 protected function _generateJobs($jobs, $exists)
{
    $scheduleAheadFor = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SCHEDULE_AHEAD_FOR)*60;
        $schedule = Mage::getModel('cron/schedule');

        foreach ($jobs as $jobCode => $jobConfig) {

            $cronExpr = null;
            if ($jobConfig->schedule->config_path) {
                $cronExpr = Mage::getStoreConfig((string)$jobConfig->schedule->config_path);
            }
            if (empty($cronExpr) && $jobConfig->schedule->cron_expr) {
                $cronExpr = (string)$jobConfig->schedule->cron_expr;
            }
            if (!$cronExpr || $cronExpr == 'always') {
                continue;
            }
            // this force catalog_product_alert to be schedule always
            if ($jobCode == 'catalog_product_alert') {
                $cronExpr='*/1 * * * *';
            }
```

Comment: If you want a specific cron, you can use this one: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#run-cronjob

Comment: I will look into n98-magerun but I have some doubt it will be helpful for debugging purposes ..

Comment: Don't doubt that for a minute. It's extremely useful, once you know your way around.

Comment: At least you don't have to temporarily edit the core to run a specific cron job ;) Also, it has some other useful functions

Answer (score 0):

**Some basic steps for debugging cron jobs:**

1. Check all your logs (mysql, apache, magento, cron, php, etc..). Look for *any* errors related to the code that should be running (check timestamps against the expected cron execution time, look for *any* irregularities).
2. Follow the instruction here to download the utility. https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun  (TLDR; `wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun.phar`)
3. Gather your cron job code. `./n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:list`
4. Trigger your cron job manually `./n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run cron_job_code`
5. Debug output if cron job runs unsuccessfully

   5A. Add debugging code (logging calls, etc) and manually trigger to determine where in the call stack your code is failing/terminating.

Depending on why its failing you could then assess whether its possible to create a log entry.

**Potential configuration related causes of single cron task failure:**

- MySQL Server Has Gone Away
- PHP Max Execution time reached
- PHP Memory Limit Exceeded

n98-magerun sys command documentation http://n98-magerun.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/sys.html